# Multiple Accounts on a single node?

Tags: accounts, nodes

I am a beginner and learning Ethereum. Can somebody please tell me if my understanding is correct?

Q) There could be just 1 node running, but multiple accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct a node can host multiple accounts. 
Have a look at :
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts

Comment: Assalamualaikum would you recommend any book that would prepare me for a blockchain developer role? I am already familiar with Spring boot, java, and node.js. I am looking for a good book to be a blockchain developer.

Comment: 1-https://www.amazon.com/Blockchain-Example-Decentralized-applications-Hyperledger-ebook/dp/B0787CGRHW

2-https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Ethereum-Building-Smart-Contracts/dp/1491971940

Comment: JazakAllah brother